# BeautifulSoup: Extract the label of checked radio button

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, radio-button

I have the radio buttons followed. How can I get the text of the `checked` radio button by `python3`? In this example, it is `Equal Width`.

```
  <li>
      <input class="bRadio" value="1" type="radio" id="main.Option1" name="main.Option" checked="checked">
      <label class="col-form-label">Equal Width</label>
  </li>
  <li>
      <input class="bRadio" value="2" type="radio" id="main.Option2" name="main.Option">
      <label class="col-form-label">Variable Width</label>
  </li>
```

I can get the checked radio button by the followed. But I have no clue how to connect with the text (label) of the button.

```
temp = tags.find_all('input', {'class' : 'bRadio', 'type' : 'radio'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(temp), 'lxml')
checked = soup.find_all('input', checked="checked")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''

  <li>
      <input class="bRadio" value="1" type="radio" id="main.Option1" name="main.Option" checked="checked">
      <label class="col-form-label">Equal Width</label>
  </li>
  <li>
      <input class="bRadio" value="2" type="radio" id="main.Option2" name="main.Option">
      <label class="col-form-label">Variable Width</label>
  </li>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def is_checked(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('checked')

wanted_text = soup.find(is_checked).find_next_sibling('label').text
print(wanted_text)
```

This returns:

```
'Equal Width'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this in JQuery:

```html
<li>
        <input class="bRadio" value="1" type="radio" id="main.Option1" name="main.Option" onchange="getId(this.id)" checked>
        <label for="main.Option1" class="col-form-label">Equal Width</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="bRadio" value="2" type="radio" id="main.Option2" name="main.Option" onchange="getId(this.id)">
        <label for="main.Option2" class="col-form-label">Variable Width</label>
    </li>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        function getId(params){
            let text = $("[for='" + params + "'").text();
            $(demo).text(text);
            // you can use wherever you want
        }
        // Setting a default value
        $(demo).text("Equal Width");
    </script>
```

Comment: I am sorry. I need a Python script. I updated my post.

Comment: warem, Oh! But I am sorry, I can't help with that as I don't use python...

Comment: It is my fault. Thanks anyway.